# ASN.1 OID of bcrypt

Tags: bcrypt, asn.1, pkcs8

What is the ASN.1 OID associated to [bcrypt](http://www.usenix.org/events/usenix99/provos/provos_html/node1.html) (the key derivation scheme)?

For instance, PBKDF2 has `1.2.840.113549.1.5.12` and it is therefore possible to store a private key in a PKCS#8 structure, encrypted with a password. Is that possible with bcrypt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://www.oid-info.com/ bcrypt has no official OID. You could register a private enterprise number with IANA and assign your own OID for your purpose. But that's going to make interaction with 3rd party application more complicated.

Or you could use PBKDF2 instead of bcrypt. PBKDF2 is a public-key cryptography standards. Libraries such as OpenSSL implement PKCS #5 and therefore provide HMAC-based PBKDF2. The algorithm provides about the same amount of security as bcrypt.

Comment: OpenSS $\mapsto$ OpenSSL $\:$ ? $\;\;\;$

Comment: Yes, OpenSSL. Thanks for the hint. I have fixed my typo.